# Array uploading in cycle step

Tags: php

I want to go deeper in the rabbit hole, but I can't get a grab on this case. Explain it please:

Why isn't this array starts from 1 (it starts from 2)?

```
$test_array = array();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++ && $test_array[] = $i);
print_r($test_array);
```

Comment: could you be clearer about your question? currently it makes no sense

Comment: Because: it starts with `$i` at zero `$i=0`, then increases that by one `$i++` before it adds it to the array for the first time `$test_array[] = $i`. In the `&&` operator the left argument is evaluated before the right argument.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware how does this answers OP's question?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Wouldn't that make the first value `1` and not `2`, which seems to be the case?

Comment: @u_mulder: It is not, it should start at 1. :-)

Comment: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: @u_mulder: Ok, explain...

Comment: The code provided is not having any description as to why are you assigning something in the increment parameter of "for" is not very clear

Comment: Well I just exploring, I didn't want to achieve anything... I just wanted to know why it acts this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's go deeper in the rabbit hole and check value of `$i`.

**1.** Our `$i = 0`. Then statement `$i++` is **false**. Because php first checks `$i` value and then increments it. So, as `$i++` is false, second part `$test_array[] = $i` does not execute.

**2.** Our `$i = 1` (increased previously). Then statement `$i++` is **true** as `$i` equals `1`. `$i` gets incremented to `2` and value `2` is written to `$test_array[]`

3,4,5 and other iterations are the same as **2**.

Comment: Big maglite for a little rabbit hole :-)

Comment: Doesn't statements run all of the sections, then comparing each part with the && comparison? Like when `$i=0` then `$i++` it will return false and `$test_array[] = $i` should return true and the && comparison would be false. Isn't php works this way?

Comment: No, php has lazy evaluation from left to right (in case of `if`), and if it's guaranteed that something makes the result `false` then nothing else will be evaluated. Why evaluate something that doesn't matter?

Comment: Ahh... So that's the case. Thank you!